# Compute $f^*: H^n(S^p \times S^q) \to H^n(S^n).$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Here is the question I am trying to tackle:

In the following exercise, let $H^*(X) = H^*(X;R)$ for any coefficient ring $R.$

Let $n = p + q$ and suppose that $f: S^n \to S^p \times S^q$ is a continuous map. Compute $$f^* : H^n(S^p \times S^q) \to H^n(S^n).$$

I am wondering how should I tackle this problem, I already calculated the integral cohomology of $S^p \times S^q$ as graded abelian groups and as graded rings and I have seen that they are equal the following respectively:

$$
1-H^n(S^p \times S^q; \mathbb Z) =\begin{cases}
 \mathbb Z, & \text{for }  n = 0, p,q,p+q \\
 0 , & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

$$2-H^*(S^p \times S^q; \mathbb Z) \cong H^*(S^p ; \mathbb Z)\otimes_R H^*(S^q; \mathbb Z)\cong$$
$$ \cong \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2) \otimes \mathbb Z[y]/(y^2) = \begin{cases}
 \mathbb Z[x,y]/(x^2, y^2, xy + yx), & \text{for odd }  p,q \\
 \mathbb Z[x,y]/(x^2, y^2, xy - yx), & \text{for even p or q or both}  
\end{cases}
$$

But if  $xy = yx \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, then we will have $xy + yx = 2xy$, and we cannot expect a 2-torsion element in the cohomology of our space. Therefore, we have that $$\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2) \otimes \mathbb Z[y]/(y^2) \cong \mathbb Z[x,y]/(x^2, y^2, xy + yx).$$

I was told that the required map that is induced in cohomology maybe the zero map to preserve the degree of $x$ and $y$ but I can not justify this rigorously. Also, I am saying that it maybe the identity map. Could anyone help me in computing this map please?

Comment: In your final expressions for $H^*(S^p \times S^q)$ — third line of the displayed math — it would be better to write $\mathbb{Z}\langle x, y \rangle/(...)$: the free algebra on $x$ and $y$, not a polynomial ring. When $p$ and $q$ are odd, $x$ and $y$ will not commute, so you don't actually have a polynomial ring.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri are you speaking about the line after $2$-?

Comment: Are you saying that if I have a polynomial ring, this implicitly means that $x,y$ commute? I did not get your point @JohnPalmieri

Comment: Yes, by definition the variables in a polynomial ring commute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the cohomology ring structure. By Künneth theorem, $H^n(S^p\times S^q)$ is generated by $x\smile y$, where $x\in H^p(S^p\times S^q)$ and $y\in H^q(S^p\times S^q)$.
Since there is an induced homomorphism $f^*:H^*(S^p\times S^q)\to H^*(S^n)$ on the cohomology rings, we can compute
$$f^*(x\smile y)=f^*(x)\smile f^*(y)$$
Since $H^p(S^n)\cong H^q(S^n)\cong 0$, we know that $f^*(x)=f^*(y)=0$. Thus, the induced homomorphism, when restricted to the top cohomology, is trivial.

Comment: Which version of Kunneth theorem in AT you are using?

Comment: On which page in AT  it states that the induced homomorphism of the cupproduct is the cupproduct of the induced homomorphism?

Comment: How did you know that we can use the cohomology ring structure?

Comment: @Brain Suppose that by AT you're talking about *Algebraic Topology* by Hatcher, this version of Künneth formula is Theorem 3.16, pg. 219, which is exactly how you computed the cohomology ring. You can easily see that the $p+q$-th cohomology is generated by the cup product.

Comment: @Brain Proposition 3.10 (pg. 210) says that the induced homomorphisms preserve cup products.

Comment: Also, what if p or q is zero, what will happen in this case?

Comment: @Brain Just imagine if $p=0$, then $S^0$ is just a set of two points, so you're essentially considering a continuous map $f:S^q\to S^q\sqcup S^q$. As continuity preserves connectedness, this map is completely determined by how $S^q$ is mapped to one of the factors. The induced homomorphism cannot be determined unless further details about $f$ is given, which I believe is not the key point of this problem, but thanks for pointing this out as I did ignore these of trivial cases in my solution.

Comment: The component $S^q$ that is not in the image of $f$ will be irrelevant to the computation. Thus, the map is can be determined by $S^q\to S^q$ (restricting the codomain of $f$). The induced homomorphism is related to the degree of $S^q\to S^q$.